# D3js V4 Center Node in Zoomable Tree

Tags: d3.js, svg

I've found this [example](http://www.robschmuecker.com/d3-js-drag-and-drop-zoomable-tree) from Rob Schmuecker for centering a node in a tree which was clicked. This example works with D3js version 3. I ported this example to [d3js version 4](https://jsfiddle.net/Tokker/mwm1sxhh/20). But in my example the svg will jump after centering if i try to move svg. Does anybody know whats going wrong? Here some code snippets.

```
var baseSvg = d3.select("#tree-container").append("svg").attr("width", viewerWidth)
                                                        .attr("height", viewerHeight)
                                                        .attr("class", "overlay")
                                                        .call(zoomListener);

function zoom() {
  if(d3.event.transform != null) {
    svgGroup.attr("transform", d3.event.transform );
  }
}

function centerNode(source) {
  t = d3.zoomTransform(baseSvg.node());
  x = -source.y0;
  y = -source.x0;
  x = x * t.k + viewerWidth / 2;
  y = y * t.k + viewerHeight / 2;
  d3.select('g').transition().duration(duration).call( zoomListener.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(x,y).scale(t.k) );
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing the selection within the centerNode from 'g' to 'svg' seems to do the trick. This is likely because the zoom listener is called on the svg element.

For reference, the centerNode function would now look like this:

```
function centerNode(source) {
  t = d3.zoomTransform(baseSvg.node());
  x = -source.y0;
  y = -source.x0;
  x = x * t.k + viewerWidth / 2;
  y = y * t.k + viewerHeight / 2;
  d3.select('svg').transition().duration(duration).call( zoomListener.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(x,y).scale(t.k) );
}
```

Comment: Thank you thats it. I've updated my example and it works. [link]https://jsfiddle.net/Tokker/mwm1sxhh/21/

Answer (score -1):

Please look at this example of [Collapsible Tree](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd) at the documentation.
It may help you and it is using the version 4 of D3.js

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the example doesn't cover my problem.